# How to give a VPC and all its instances access to a AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, aws-vpc

My goal is simple:

Allow any instance inside a VPC to connect to a specific security group.

The field for allowed sources suggests: "CIDR, IP or Security group".

Is there a way for me to specify a VPC?

The reason beeing that I have multiple instances inside a VPC with different security groups but all need access to the security group I am creating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your VPC has a CIDR group range, so just specify the CIDR group that is being used by your VPC and it will allow access from anything in the VPC.

Comment: I see. What could be the issue for failed pings between two instances set up as described? Both VPC's have internet gateways set up and assigned to the routing tables.

Comment: You mean using the actual `ping` command? Ping uses the ICMP protocol, which is not usually open on AWS. You would have to add a rule to your security group allowing ICMP traffic. `ping` isn't really the best method of testing connectivity on AWS. Also what do you mean by "both VPC's"? Your question is about a single VPC. If you talking about cross-VPC traffic then you need to enable VPC Peering http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html

Comment: uh oh. I intended to have a security group in another VPC to allow traffic from a different VPC. I guess thats the problem at stake. Thank you for you help I will look into Peering

Comment: Yeah these VPC IP ranges are internal to the VPC. You have to setup VPC peering before the other VPC can see traffic coming from those internal IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is the primary functionality of a security group. For example, if the CIDR of the VPC you want to allow is `10.4.0.0/16`,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the Inbound route to the required CIDR group. The Outbound will automatically be set as per AWS VPC design.